# Show progress bar in single line

Tags: python, progress, tqdm

I want to show the progress bar in a single line.
I have written the code

```
from tqdm import tqdm
from time import sleep
def test():  
     my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
     for i in tqdm(my_list):
         print(i)
         sleep(.1)
```

I get the output as follows:

[image]

It shows the incremental progress in separate lines.
Is there any way to get the progress bar to show progress in the same line as shown below?

[image]

I tried removing the print statement. Result as follows:

[image]

Comment: Not sure why this was marked as a duplicate, these are different questions. One is for printing additional content with a progress bar and the other is for capturing input when using a progress bar.

Answer (score 1):

Your statement `print(i)` is polluting the output. Remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Just end your print with `end="\033[K"`.

```
from tqdm import tqdm
from time import sleep


def test():
    my_list = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "a", "b", "c", "d", "a", "b", "c", "d"]
    for i in tqdm(my_list):
        print(i, end="\033[K")
        sleep(0.1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not using the `print(i)`

```
 from tqdm import tqdm
    from time import sleep
    def test():  
        my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
        for i in tqdm(my_list):
            sleep(.1)
        
test()
```

Answer (score 0):

### tldr: Use tqdm.write instead of print

This is due to you using `print`. Since `tqdm` is a very simple progress bar (no curses, only uses the standard output), it can only print on the current line. Since you are using `print`, you change the current line.

If you still need to print messages to stdout, you can use the `.write` method of tqdm instead, like this:

```py
 from tqdm import tqdm
 from time import sleep
 def test():  
     my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
     for i in tqdm(my_list):
         tqdm.write(i)
         sleep(.1)
```

See more details here:

https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm#writing-messages

Comment: Or use [Enlighten](https://pypi.org/project/enlighten) instead which handles this automatically